# strange noise after trying to process large amounts of data

Tags: r, onedrive, large-data

I apologize in advance for the somewhat vague question, but I dont have anyone else to ask. I was running the following code in R:

```
library(SAScii)
parse.SAScii("16crime.sas", beginline = 14)
x <- read.SAScii("opafy16nid.dat", "16crime.sas", beginline = 14)
```

the .dat file is 2.3 gigs which is large, at least for my computer specs, but seemingly do-able. Originally I tried running it on my windows onedrive, which should have about 9 Gigs of free space. I have a RAM of 8 Gigs. After it ran for about 8 hours and R showed about 16,000 records processed my computer started making a very bizarre noise. It almost sounded like it does when calling a fax machine ( this is the vague part i apologize for) for about 3 minutes, after that the noise ceased. Everything froze and i was unable to do a thing. Against my better judgement after about an hour of waiting for something to happened, i forced shutdown on my computer and rebooted. Seemingly, everything is working fine now and running scans on harddrive came back with no errors. I want to try it again because the data never completed loading into R, but i dont want my computer to blow up either. Can anyone comment to that noise and if i should try this again?

Comment: The .SAS file has the record layout, and the dat file is  just a text file. You can open the .sas file with a text editor, convert it to true R code and read it. The file is 2.3 GB which will give you a 80-100 million record data set (rough guess). R, in my experience, will have trouble with a data set that size without any modifications to the default settings.

Comment: well, it sounds like and 80-100 million record file, when 16,000 records took about 8 hours, is out of my computers league with this method. Would any of the changes to R's default settings you speak of change this significantly enough as to make it load in a day or so? I tried using hj split to break the dat file into smaller chunks but it appear to mess up the formating as such that R or sas could not longer make sense of it.

Comment: It's a text file so not sure what hj split is, but you could easily use Powershell commands to split the files. For tasks like this the OS commands are usually the fastest. I suspect something happened that caused it to error out. 8 hours for 16K records is too long for any application, even Excel is faster :)

Comment: Yea i could see that. Fow what its worth, I think each record have have a couple hundred varibales though. Theoretically this is supposed to be every single bit of information gathered for every single crime in the US over a whole year. race, age crime, sentence, loaction, etc. Okay i will toy around with it some more. thanks Reeza

Comment: Is this open data? If you can send a link I can take a look at the file directly.

Comment: Yes. Here is the website with the zip files... https://www.ussc.gov/research/datafiles/commission-datafiles. the specific one I am working with is under "indivdual offenders data files", and the link to the zip is Fiscal year 2016.

Comment: It has 22408 variables and 67742 observations, but is a 4GB data set. I would think that should fit in R but not sure about the size restrictions. Can you read the dat file with some other method? It's a fixed width file, ie variables are always in the same locations. What kind of record layout would make that easier? It took 2 minutes to read/process the entire file in SAS.

Comment: Wait you loaded it into R in 2 minutes?! and mine is reading 2.25 gig. how bizzare. Sorry i would go to chat but i am not ranked high enough. Also i was going to include a screen shot showing my dat file at 2.25 but I am not sure i can do that.

Comment: The DAT file is 2.25GB, I loaded it into SAS (not R) and it took less than 2 minutes to read it all in. The created file, SAS data set is 4GB. Not sure how big the R data frame would be.

Comment: okay, well if it is 22k records and i made it to 16k I was close! Ill move the data to harddrive which has 30gb of free space and give it a shot on there. I cant imagine it can damage it

Comment: lol, I was going to put the R code, but it's 45452 characters which is too long for SO apparently.

Comment: See the code here, it expires in 24 hours. Imanually pulled the lengths from SAS and put them in the R code, using readr package to read fixed width files. https://pastebin.com/BYHu9yAF

Comment: Could it have been your computer's fans? I imagine that what your computer was doing produced quite a lot of heat and was probably running your fans really hard. If something failed with the motors or they were grinding against something that could make a noise like that. A fan failure would also cause overheating which could explain the crash. That's just a guess, though.

Comment: Reeza, that code shows an emptry argument error 2017 is empty

Comment: Check if pastebin added EOL characters. You can use a tex editor like notepadd++ to remove them. It works for me so the idea should be clear. The numbers are from the length statement in the .sas file. Both your .sas and .dat file are text so the overall point is the same. The package obviously has some issues, so doing it the R way is your best bet. It took less than 5 minutes for it to run on my computer with 8GB RAM.